# how to monitor every ui frame draw time when develop on android

Tags: android, user-interface

i am looking for a solution to monitor ui performance. When user touch screen,the view will update.and i want to know the time duration of this action cost

- how to monitor ui performance on android?
- can i  monitor every ui frame draw time?

It seems that there is no API;

Comment: You can go to developer settings on device and enable: Frame rate display, and re-draw regions. Even better is to enable strict mode. Android will draw red outlines around views it finds too slow.

Comment: but i want to monitor every action and record the time use! Frame rate display,and re-draw regions these functions can not run on low level devices. thank u anyway~